# How to write a simple Java program that finds the greatest common divisor between two numbers?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

Here is the question:

"Write a method named gcd that accepts two integers as parameters and returns the greatest common divisor of the two numbers. The greatest common divisor (GCD) of two integers a and b is the largest integer that is a factor of both a and b. The GCD of any number and 1 is 1, and the GCD of any number and 0 is that number.

One efficient way to compute the GCD of two numbers is to use Euclid's algorithm, which states the following:

```
GCD(A, B) = GCD(B, A % B) 
GCD(A, 0) = Absolute value of A"
```

I'm really confused as to how to solve this problem. I just want some hints and tips as to what I did wrong in the program I have so far. (I have to put in a Scanner, that is my teacher's requirement.)
Don't give me a full code as I kinda want to solve this out myself. Maybe just give me a hint on how I incorporate this formula that you see above. (And if you're wondering why I put in the == 0, it's because I thought that if you have two numbers, say 0 and 90, their GCD would be 0 right??)

Also, my code has to include while loops...I would've preferred if loops...

Thanks in advance! :)

My current program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = console.nextInt();
        int b = console.nextInt();
        gcd (a, b);
    }

    public static void gcd(int a, int b) {
        System.out.print("Type in two numbers and I will print outs its Greatest Common Divisor: ");
        int gcdNum1 = console.nextInt();
        int gcdNum2 = console.nextInt();
        while (gcdNum1 == 0) {
            gcdNum1 = 0;
        }
        while (gcdNum2 > gcdNum1) {
            int gcd = gcdNum1 % gcdNum2;
        }
        System.out.print(gcdNum1 + gcdNum2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint - you need a recursive call.

Comment: You are passing `a` and `b` to your method as paramters, so there is no need to read them again from console (and `console` variable is not visible in the method, so your code won't compile anyway). Also, the first loop looks pretty infinite, if entered.

Comment: *I would've preferred if loops...* That's quite complicated since `if` is no loop

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Haha typo.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A recursive method would be:

```
static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  if(a == 0 || b == 0) return a+b; // base case
  return gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

Using a while loop:

```
static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  while(a!=0 && b!=0) // until either one of them is 0
  {
     int c = b;
     b = a%b;
     a = c;
  }
  return a+b; // either one is 0, so return the non-zero value
}
```

When I'm returning `a+b`, I'm actually returning the non-zero number assuming one of them is 0.

Comment: I think your code assumes a > b, if someone calls gcd(2, 20), it won't work.

Comment: @Patrick It would. In the next step, it would call gcd(20,2)

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it in a three line method:

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y){
  return (y == 0) ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

Here, if `y = 0`, x is returned.  Otherwise, the `gcd` method is called again, with different parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int GCD(int x, int y) {   
    int r;
    while (y!=0) {
        r = x%y;
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {




public static void  main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
    int b = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the second integer:");
    int d = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The GCD of " + b + " and " + d + " is " +  getGcd(b,d) + ".");
}


public static int getGcd(int b, int d)
{
    int gcd = 1;

    if(b>d)
    {
        for(int i = d; i >=1; i--)
        {
            if(b%i==0 && d%i ==0)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j = b; j >=1; j--)
        {
            if(b%j==0 && d% j==0)
            {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }   
    return gcd;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the code below:

```
        int gcd = 0;
        while (gcdNum2 !=0 && gcdNum1 != 0 ) {
        if(gcdNum1 % gcdNum2 == 0){
            gcd = gcdNum2;
        }
            int aux = gcdNum2; 
            gcdNum2 = gcdNum1 % gcdNum2;
            gcdNum1 = aux;
    }
```

You do not need recursion to do this.

And be careful, it says that when a number is zero, then the GCD is the number that is not zero.

```
    while (gcdNum1 == 0) {
    gcdNum1 = 0;
}
```

You should modify this to fulfill the requirement.

I am not going to tell you how to modify your code entirely, only how to calculate the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void GCD(int a, int b) {

    int temp;
    // make a greater than b
    if (b > a) {
         temp = a;
         a = b;
         b = temp;
    }

    while (b !=0) {
        // gcd of b and a%b
        temp = a%b;
        // always make a greater than bf
        a =b;
        b =temp;

    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CalculateGCD 
{   
  public static int calGCD(int a, int b) 
  { 
   int c=0,d=0;  
   if(a>b){c=b;} 
   else{c=a;}  
   for(int i=c; i>0; i--) 
   { 
    if(((a%i)+(b%i))==0) 
    { 
     d=i; 
     break; 
    } 
   } 
   return d;  
  }  

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  { 
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
   System.out.println("Enter the nos whose GCD is to be calculated:"); 
   int a=sc.nextInt(); 
   int b=sc.nextInt(); 
   System.out.println(calGCD(a,b));  
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I just started programing about a week ago, so nothing fancy, but I had this as a problem and came up with this, which may be easier for people who are just getting into programing to understand. It uses Euclid's method like in previous examples.

```
public class GCD {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = Math.max(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]));    
    int y = Math.min(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]));     
    for (int r = x % y; r != 0; r = x % y){
      x = y;
      y = r;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```